Ubuntu 22.04 Oh No - Something went wrong after using Mouse/Keyboard input
I upgraded Ubuntu from 22.04 to 24.04 because I was asked by the System if I wanted to upgrade and after the whole process i got the message "Oh No - Something went wrong", when I was pressing a key or moving the mouse in the Desktop Environment. The error always occurs after using an input device in the usual Desktop environment and is not a white screen like I read a few times.
During the upgrading i was asked if I wanted to upgrade grub as well but I did deny it and stayed with the old version.
There has not been any errors during the upgrade.
Any idea what could be the solution?

What message? Were there any errors or issues during the upgrade? What did you upgrade from? What steps did you preform to do the upgrade? As you can see your question needs some detail. Please edit the question and add some details.

Thanks, I edited the post
